# Why we can write functions as "infinite" power series?

Tags: power-series

If we look at the definition of "function", we can see it as a "relation" between two sets, or "mapping" of a given element to another element, my question is: why we can represent this relation as infinite summation of a simple polynomial? In particular, why "infinite"? I see it like a strange thing.

Comment: You can't represent an arbitrary function as a power series.  Functions that can be represented as a power series are rather special - they're called "analytic". In particular, they must be differentiable to all orders.

Comment: @JairTaylor I know that. And I'm asking for this also, what is the restriction? I read about analytic function definition, but the definition says "it can be represented by power series...", which says nothing for me at least.

Comment: Not sure if it's too helpful, but see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function#Alternative_characterizations) for characterizations of analyticity.  For complex-valued functions it is rather simpler: they are analytic if and only if they are complex-differentiable on a domain.

Comment: My intuition is that polynomials are not simple, but surprisingly complicated.  For example, you can write down a polynomial going through any finite number of points ([Lagrange interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial)), and you can approximate any continuous function on a bounded interval using polynomials ([Stone-Weierstrass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem)).  You have more and more parameters to set as the degree of a polynomial increasing, so the set of polynomials becomes more and more expressive.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, in general, write a function as a power series: e.g. $\chi_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)=\begin{cases} 0\ x\in \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}\\1\ x\in \mathbb{Q}\end{cases}$ (actually, this is true for "most" of the functions, where most can be precised in a quite technical manner).
 You can, however, do it for a quite useful set of functions (namely, the [analytic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function?wprov=sfla1). A necessary condition for a function to be analytic js for it to be infinitely differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$, while in $\mathbb{C}$ being differentiable is a necessary and sufficient condition), which are defined as the functions that can be written as a power series.

So, not all of the functions can be represented as a power series. Between the analytic functions, however, why must we  use an infinite sum? Well, that is simply because finite sums of polynomials are not enough: for a start, they cannot have an infinite set of zeros which is not the whole domain, while many interesting functions do ($\sin(x),\cos(x)...$). And for this reason we include an infinite numbers of addendums.

Since we have covered why an infinite sum, I am tempted to go on and analyze why a sum of polynomials.

A first answer is that these kind of sum comes naturally as a limit process from the [Taylor expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem?wprov=sfla1). But this is not the only reason. As stated in the comments by JamesTaylor, the set of polynomials satisfy a number of properties (they form a sub-algebra, with a constant, that separates points) that makes them fit to approximate the continuous function on an interval (thanks to the [Stone-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem?wprov=sfla1)).

As a final note, we do not use only infinite sum of polynomials to describe functions. We use a lot of functions: as an example, [Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series?wprov=sfla1) are infinite sums of sines and cosines, and with those we are able to describe a larger class of functions than the class of analytics functions. In general, in an infinite dimensional [Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space?wprov=sfla1) we are able to write its elements as the infinite sum of some special elements, called a Hilbert basis of the space.